# How to properly validate a MultipleChoiceField in a Django form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a MultipleChoiceField representing US states, and passing a GET request to my form like `?state=AL%2CAK` results in the error:

```
Select a valid choice. AL,AK is not one of the available choices.
```

However, these values are definitely listed in the fields choices, as they're rendered in the form field correctly.

I've tried specifying a custom clean_state() method in my form, to convert the value to a list, but that has no effect. Printing the cleaned_data['state'] seems to show it's not even being called with the data from request.GET.

What's causing this error?

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    state = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
        required=False,
        choices=[('AL','Alabama'),('AK','Alaska')],
    )
```

Comment: Please show us your form or just the field you have created for choices.

Comment: @AamirAdnan, Posted. It's fairly simple.

Comment: does it validate when you just select single state?

Answer (score 0):

MultipleChoiceFields don't pass all of the selected values in a list, they pass several different values for the same key instead.

In other words, if you select 'AL' and 'AK' your querystring should be `?state=AL&state=AK` instead of `?state=AL%2CAK`.

Without seeing your custom `clean_state()` method I can't tell you what's going wrong with it, but if the state field isn't valid because the querystring is wrong then 'state' won't be in cleaned_data (because cleaned_data only holds valid data).

Hopefully that helps. If you're still stuck try adding a few more details and I can try to be more specific.